# My formulas work, but do not refer to the row being worked on in my With loop

Tags: excel, vba

Using a UserForm in Excel VBA, I cannot seem to make my formula section to refer to cells on the current row being used in my code. I do not want it to only refer to row 2 data. Row 1 is a header row.

How can I do this?

```
Private Sub cmdAccept_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim fieldData As Worksheet
    lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

RowCount = Worksheets("fieldData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("fieldData").Range("A1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_dateDelivered.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.comboBox_fieldData_fieldName.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_acres.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.comboBox_fieldData_crop.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product1.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product2.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product3.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product4.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product5.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product6.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 10).Value = "=Range($E2:$J2)"
    .Offset(RowCount, 11).Value = "=SUM((11.06*$E2)+(11.7*$F2)+(11.04*$G2)+(10.9*$H2)+(10.28*$I2)+(9.5*$J2)"
    .Offset(RowCount, 12).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(32/100)/$C2)+((11.7*$F2)*(10/100)/$C2)+((11.04*$G2)*(12/100)/$C2)+((10.9*$H2)*(8/100)/$C2)+((10.28*$I2)*(7/100)/$C2)+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C2))"
    .Offset(RowCount, 13).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((11.7*$F2)*(34/100)/$C2)+((11.04*$G2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((10.9*$H2)*(25/100)/$C2)+((10.28*$I2)*(24/100)/$C2)+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C2))"
    .Offset(RowCount, 14).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((11.7*$F2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((11.04*$G2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((10.9*$H2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((10.28*$2I)*(0/100)/$C2)+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C2))"
    .Offset(RowCount, 15).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((11.7*$F2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((11.04*$G2)*(26/100)/$C2)+((10.9*$H2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((10.28*$I2)*(0/100)/$C2)+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C2))"
End With
End Sub
```

The user will input specific data into the UserForm, which will fill columns 1 thru column 10, click on an "Accept Data", then the formulas should run and the results be placed in the same row from column K thru column P. Once complete, the user will continue to input data, until they press the "Close" CommandButton.

Comment: `With` isn't a looping structure. I'm guessing you need a [For loop](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures/8169/for-loop).

Answer (score 0):

Let me know how this works for you.

```
Private Sub cmdAccept_Click()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim fieldData As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("fieldData")
        x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        .Cells(x, 1).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_dateDelivered.Value
        .Cells(x, 2).Value = Me.comboBox_fieldData_fieldName.Value
        .Cells(x, 3).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_acres.Value
        .Cells(x, 4).Value = Me.comboBox_fieldData_crop.Value
        .Cells(x, 5).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product1.Value
        .Cells(x, 6).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product2.Value
        .Cells(x, 7).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product3.Value
        .Cells(x, 8).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product4.Value
        .Cells(x, 9).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product5.Value
        .Cells(x, 10).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product6.Value
        .Cells(x, 11).Value = "=Range($E2:$J2)"
        .Cells(x, 12).Value = "=SUM((11.06*$E2)+(11.7*$F2)+(11.04*$G" & x & ")+(10.9*$H" & x & ")+(10.28*$I2)+(9.5*$J2)"
        .Cells(x, 13).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(32/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.7*$F2)*(10/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.04*$G" & x & ")*(12/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.9*$H" & x & ")*(8/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.28*$I2)*(7/100)/$C" & x & ")+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & "))"
        .Cells(x, 14).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.7*$F2)*(34/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.04*$G" & x & ")*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.9*$H" & x & ")*(25/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.28*$I2)*(24/100)/$C" & x & ")+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & "))"
        .Cells(x, 15).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.7*$F2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.04*$G" & x & ")*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.9*$H" & x & ")*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.28*$2I)*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & "))"
        .Cells(x, 16).Value = "=SUM(((11.06*$E2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.7*$F2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((11.04*$G" & x & ")*(26/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.9*$H" & x & ")*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((10.28*$I2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & ")+((9.5*$J2)*(0/100)/$C" & x & "))"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the last used row in Column A?

Comment: @JDStewart I modified the code to append a record to `Worksheets("fieldData")` every time `cmdAccept` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Thomas, SO much for opening my eyes to other methods of coding!!! This is the code I used making the formulas work...

```
Private Sub cmdAccept_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim fieldData As Worksheet
Set fieldData = Worksheets("fieldData")

RowCount = fieldData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
With fieldData
    .Cells(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_dateDelivered.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.comboBox_fieldData_fieldName.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_acres.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.comboBox_fieldData_crop.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product1.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product2.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product3.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product4.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product5.Value
    .Cells(RowCount, 10).Value = Me.txtBox_fieldData_product6.Value
    .Range("K" & RowCount - 1 & ":P" & RowCount).FillDown
End With
```

End Sub